# Passing directives as content for VIS items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have been using visjs.org/docs/timeline/ to show a timeline view of the data. I have a directive that takes the data from the API and creates template using the `$compile` method.

```
<vis-timeline timeline-data="apiData"></vis-timeline>
```

And in the `linkFn` I'm iterating through the data to create scope for the template which is to be passed as the content for the vis `DataSet`.

```
link: function(scope,element,attr){
   if(scope.roster.timelineData){

     angular.forEach(scope.roster.timelineData, function(){

     //Create a scope for the directive used for vis DataSet
     var templateScope = scope.$new(true);//create an isolated scope

     templateScope.name = 'templateData';
     //this can be different for each iteration

     var template = $compile('<timeline-item template-data="name"></timeline-item>')(templateScope)[0];

     });
   }
 }
```

I push the compiled template as a content for the vis `DataSet` which gets added to the timeline. Even though this method works well, it takes around 10 seconds for building the timeline. Any edit to the timeline would take another 10 seconds to reflect.

If I add a plain template instead of it, it does get added fast. How to improve the speed of compiling templates?

Comment: Is it the same directive `timeline-item` and same template string `'<timeline-item template-data="name"></timeline-item>'` all the time?

Comment: Would be great if you'll setup [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the issue you are facing.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Yes it is the same directive but the scope would vary . Above mentioned is just an example to detail the issue .

Comment: Depending what are you doing farther with your `template` variable you can cache a partial result of `$compile` like `var compiledTemplate = $compile('<timeline-item template-data="name"></timeline-item>');`ouside of linking function and then use it like [`compiledTemplate(scope, function(clonedElement, scope){ ... })`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) where `clonedElement` is a clone of the original element passed into the compiler. But still would be great to have `mcve` from you to be able to understand the problem a bit more.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash Provided above should be sufficient mcve isn't it ?

Comment: I still don't see what are you doing next with the `template` variable, we still don't know how `timeline-item` component works, so this doesn't seem to be a good `mcve`, probably you can set up a fiddle that will show the problem. But still I advice you to move `$compile(..)` at least from `forEach` loop, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: timeline-item is just a sample directive that would serve as the template for a DataSet in vis library . The compiled template is passed as the content for the vis library .

Comment: So try caching a compiled template and get the element as the first argument of the `cloneAttachFn` like `compiledTemplate(templateScope, function(clonedElement, scope){ var template = clonedElement[0]; }) `.